# Swift - NSLayout Table with SpriteNodes and UILabel

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

im still working on my first iPhone game with Xcode and Swift.

The game works fine so i thought i could add some features to the game. One of them is a Scene where the player can see his stats.

So i have created one Background for the scene `(SKSpriteNodes)` and i have added some `UILabels` to the scene.

For iPhone 6 Plus the first UILabel is at the right place `(using NSLayout)`:
[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

So now i have tested it on the iPhone 5 for example .. that how it looks like:
[image: iPhone 5]

My Code so far ..

```
func StatsLabelsAnzeigen(){
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.textColor = SKColor.darkGrayColor()
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.alpha = 1
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.text = "\(HoechsteScore)" // (Int)

    self.view?.addSubview(StatHoechsteScoreLabel)

    // Create Constraints
    let RechtsbuendigStatHoechsteScoreLabel:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: StatHoechsteScoreLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    let ObenbuendigStatHoechsteScoreLabel:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: StatHoechsteScoreLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 168)
    let heightStatHoechsteScoreLabel = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[StatHoechsteScoreLabel(40)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["StatHoechsteScoreLabel" : StatHoechsteScoreLabel])
    let widthStatHoechsteScoreLabel = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[StatHoechsteScoreLabel(200)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["StatHoechsteScoreLabel" : StatHoechsteScoreLabel])

    // Add the created Constraints
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.addConstraints(heightStatHoechsteScoreLabel)
    StatHoechsteScoreLabel.addConstraints(widthStatHoechsteScoreLabel)
    self.view?.addConstraint(RechtsbuendigStatHoechsteScoreLabel)
    self.view?.addConstraint(ObenbuendigStatHoechsteScoreLabel)
```

My Stats-Background:

```
    StatsSceneBGNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "StatsBG2")
    StatsSceneBGNode.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width*80/100, height: view.frame.size.height*80/100)
    StatsSceneBGNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    StatsSceneBGNode.zPosition = 2
    StatsSceneBGNode.name = "StatsSceneBGNode"
    addChild(StatsSceneBGNode)
```

Is it somehow possible to make the Constraints more flexible so that it looks good for every iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, more recently apple has made this easier than before. 
If you're in your storyboard, you can cntl-drag from your labels to other labels or to the background itself. You can statically space the objects, or dynamically group and evenly space them. This is what it looks like when you cntl-drag to the background to the side of a scroll view: 
[image]
and to another object (in this case, a button):
[image]

You can use the little buttons in the lower right to make specific adjustments to your positioning:
[image]

If you're looking to do it programmatically, rather than through the storyboard, then you can find the variable names to edit such constraints in the 'View Controller Scene' side scroll bar in the storyboard. Just make a couple examples of what you want to do in the storyboard (that you can afterwards delete), and you'll see the variable names for them:
[image]

Comment: Thank you my friend. It worked just as described :-)

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help